# Nonsense RFC 4604 forbids IGMP General Queries in SSM range but IGMP General Queries have no range and are send to 224.0.0.1, the all-systems address?

Tags: routing, ipv4, multicast, rfc, igmp

- > RFC 4604 Using Internet Group Management Protocol Version 3 (IGMPv3) and Multicast Listener Discovery Protocol Version 2 (MLDv2) for Source-Specific Multicast:
  > **2.2.3. IGMPv1 Queries, IGMPv2 and MLDv1 General Queries**
  > If an IGMPv1 Query, or an IGMPv2 or MLDv1 **General Query** is received, the SFGMP protocol specifications require the host to revert to the older (IGMPv1, IGMPv2, or MLDv1) mode of operation on that interface.
  > If this occurs, the host will stop reporting source-specific subscriptions on that interface and will start using IGMPv1, IGMPv2, or MLDv1 to report interest in all SSM destination addresses, unqualified by a source address.
  > As a result, SSM semantics will no longer be applied to the multicast group address by the router.
- > **A router compliant with this document would never generate an IGMPv1, IGMPv2, or MLDv1 query for an address in the SSM range**

How does it make sense, to say "[General] query for an address in the SSM range"?

I'm not confusing this sentence with Group-Specific Queries, because for them in RFC 4604 is seperate section.

Routers send General Queries empty without a address:

> **RFC 2236 Internet Group Management Protocol, Version 2**
> In a Membership Query message, the group address field is set to zero when sending a General Query

And they send it to all hosts via 224.0.0.1.

> **RFC 2236 Internet Group Management Protocol, Version 2**
> A General Query is addressed to the all-systems multicast group (224.0.0.1)

How should it be possible, to forbid Generael Queries to the SSM range (232.0.0.0 to 232.255.255.255), when all hosts receive the Queries?

The only possibilites what this means:

1. A Router never generates IGMPv1/IGMPv2/MLDv1 Queries? (Then IGMP doesn't work well in compatibility mode)
2. I missunderstand something completely.